# Dont know how to read this method

Tags: c#, for-loop

What is this function, I mean for the part where is 0x30? Hex value that points to ASCII table?
This is probably basic stuff, and I'm without knowledge currently.

```
getCompleteCode("11111");

private string getCompleteCode(string code)
        {
            var b1 = 10;
            var b2 = 20;
            var sum = 0;
            for (var i = code.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--) 
            {
                var z = code[i] - 0x30;
                sum = sum + (z + b1) * b2;

            }

            Console.WriteLine(sum);

            return code;
}
```

Comment: 0x30 is the character '0'. Thus subtracting 0x30 from the current character (`code[i]`) should give that character's numerical value. Has the obvious flaw of no bounds checks to make sure that the char is *actually* numeric. The math with b1 and b2 seems context specific. Hard to guess.

Comment: It's pretty horrible code, especially if used in a production environment.  It's overly verbose, has magic numbers all over the place and tries to be clever by slipping in 0x30 instead of just using '0'.

Comment: C# `string` and `char` don't use ASCII. 0x30 is UTF-16 for '0'. In code, `'0'` is a lot easier to read. UTF-16 is one of several encodings for the Unicode character set. (UTF-8 is very often used for files and streams, such as this web page.) [BTW—Java, JavaScript, HTML, XML, … all use Unicode, too.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have explained, `var z = code[i] - 0x30` is standard code to get the value of a digit character.  As Glorin Oakenfoot mentioned, this code doesn't do any bounds checking.  So it works great for '0' - 0x30 (effectively, that's '0' - '0', by the way), and for '9' - 0x30.  But it will also produce weirdness like 'A' - 0x30 = 32.

Glorin's comment is also right - the rest of the numbers seem very context specific.  It seems likely to be a hash function - it calculates a mostly-unique number for a given string.  I'll walk you through the loop, but what it's doing doesn't make any real sense.  Rather than inputting "11111", let's look at "12345":

1st time through loop: i = 4, code[i] = '5', z = 5, sum = 0 + 15 * 20 = 300

2nd time through loop: i = 3, code[i] = '4', z = 4, sum = 300 + 14 * 20 = 580

3rd time through loop: i = 2, code[i] = '3', z = 3, sum = 580 + 13 * 20 = 840

4th time through loop: i = 1, code[i] = '2', z = 2, sum = 840 + 12 * 20 = 1080

5th time through loop: i = 0, code[i] = '1', z = 1, sum = 1080 + 11 * 20 = 1300

As I mentioned, it's likely this is used for hashing.  Every string of digits you enter is likely to have a unique integer code.  Hashing of strings can improve efficiency.  If nothing else, it gives you a fairly robust test for comparison. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function

Of course, most string hash functions don't do the conversion from digit to int.  And if the function requires that the input be only digits, as seems to be implied by the conversion to int, the simplest hash for this string is to just parse it to an integer.

The other thing this reminds me of is an attempt to parse an integer string to a digit.  That would be very similar, but note the differences below:

```
var sum = 0
for (var i = 0; i < code.Length; i++)
{
    var z = code[i] - '0' // this is the same as - 0x30, but more clear to read
    sum = sum * 10 + z
}
```

Considering the name of the function, though, it seems much more likely that it's intended as a hash function.

Comment: It seems to be not a hash algorithm exactly - for a good hash, you would multiply by a prime number, like 19, instead of by 20.  It's not the Luhn algorithm to verify a credit card number, it's not a crc algorithm...

Comment: no-one knows what is it (hash, some encoding, kind of control number, just a homework); for me it's a good example of how one *should not* implement a logic (mark at least five errors in the code and you'll pas the quiz) ;)

Answer (score 3):

A wonderful example of how one *should not* implement a logic:

```
    // why not static?
    private string getCompleteCode(string code)
    {
        // what does "b1" as well as "b2" stand for?
        var b1 = 10;
        var b2 = 20;
        var sum = 0;
        // the reason for the loop being in reversed order? 
        for (var i = code.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--) 
        {
            // the question put - what does 0x30 stand for - it's ascii code of '0' char 
            // so, why magic code 0x30 instead of evident '0'?
            var z = code[i] - 0x30;
            sum = sum + (z + b1) * b2;
        }

        // what if I want to compute it in, say, WinForms?? 
        // Never mix business logic (computing some code) and UI (output) 
        Console.WriteLine(sum);

        // we've done a lot of stuff just to return the initial input?? 
        return code;
    }
```

My suggestion for the implementation (providing that `code` is guaranteed to be a correct input):

```
    //TODO: think on a better name for the method
    private static int getCompleteCode(string code) {
      return code.Sum(c => (c - '0' + 10) * 20);
    }

    ...

    Console.WriteLine(getCompleteCode("11111"));
```

Comment: Agree, I would add an `int.TryParse` on the `code` parameter and if it returns false, probably throw an exception, otherwise continue with the `code.Sum` call.

Comment: @gmiley: had method been `public` one, *validation* (via `int.TryParse` as you've proposed) would be *mandatory* (`public` method must work with *any* input). However, the method is `private`, and so we can suggest that validation is performed somewhere and we are guaranteed that input is always correct one.

Comment: Yes, I realized only a moment ago that we were dealing with `private`, but it was too late to revise my comment so I wasn't going to bother. That is correct though, being `private` valid input can be assumed.

Comment: While it's not easy to tell from the OP if this is the case, the "proper" way to get the numeric value of a character digit is `char.GetNumericValue`.  For `'0'` this will return `0.0`.  This also works for digits from other cultures.  As mentioned this may not be needed here depending on the OP's requirements, I just felt it was worth mentioning for others that may actually want to get the numeric value of a digit.

Comment: @Kyle: `char.GetNumericValue()` is really worth mentioning; it's especially helpful when you are designing *multicultural* software. e.g. `char.GetNumericValue('۲');` will return `2` for the *pesrian digit* `'۲'`

Answer (score 0):

0x30 y the hex ASCII code for number 0, so z will actually give you the digit in number type.

Answer (score 0):

0x30 is the ascii value of '0' ... it is normally used to subtract from a character, e.g. '8' - 0x30 = 8 after casting to an integer (either implicitly or explicitly like here).

Answer (score -1):

It removes decimals. It = whatever number rounded.